# L = {⟨M⟩ : there does not exist w ∈$Σ^*$ such that M rejects w } is in coRE?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

given this lanauge:
$L=\left\{\langle M\rangle\right.$ : there does not exist $\mathrm{w} \in \Sigma^*$ such that M rejects $\left.\mathrm{w}\right\}$.

how can I determine whether it is in $R, R E \backslash R, \operatorname{coRE} \backslash R$, or $\overline{R E \cup c o R E}$?

I tried to prove the it is in $coRE\backslash R$, by reducing from the following language:
$E_{T M}=\{\langle M\rangle: L(M)=\emptyset\}$
but I'm not sure
I can iterate over $\Sigma^*$ where it might be infinite run on a Turing machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ is clearly not recursive: given a Turing machine $M$, consider $\overline{M}$ the machine where you reverse accepting and rejecting states.

Then it is clear that $\langle M\rangle\in E_{TM}$ if and only if $\langle \overline{M}\rangle \in L$.

However, $L$ is indeed in $coRE$, this can be proved by [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)): given a Turing machine $M$, the following algorithm will halt in finite time and answer correctly if $\langle M\rangle \notin L$, and never halts if $\langle M \rangle \in L$ (we consider inputs in lexicographic order for example):

```
n ← 1
while true:
    for i = 1 to n:
        simulate one more step of computation of M on the nth input;
        if it halts and rejects, then return false;
    n ← n + 1
```